# GitHub анонимный коммит

Tags: git, github, auth, push, ssh-key

Сгенерировал новый SSH ключ и добавил его в настройках на GitHub. Затем создал репозиторий, импортировал его к себе и после пуша своего локального коммита на GitHub я не вижу свою аватарку и коммиты не засчитываются в мою статистику, имя одинаковое.
Вместо своего аватара вижу вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас, скорей всего, почта отличается.

Посмотрите в git консоли email:

```
git config user.email
```

Если не совпадает с тем, что вы используете на github, то установите:

```
git config user.email "your_github_email@example.com"
```

Или можете добавить ещё один email в настройки гитхаба:

[Github Settings > Emails > Add email address](https://github.com/settings/emails)